# Z-transform and region of convergence of $x(n)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{|n|}-\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n} u(n)\right]$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, z-transform

How can we find the Z-transform of
$$
x(n)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{|n|}-\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n} u(n)\right]
$$
and it's region of convergence (ROC) ??
where the Z-transform of x(n) is  $X(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] z^{-n}$ .and u(n)=1, n>=0 and 0 otherwise.

For the second part involving $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n} u(n)$,  we know how to solve it and find its region of convergence by simply transforming it into geometric series. |z|>1/2. but my problem is regarding the first term with the absolute value of n.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Note.  "Z-transform" is not a term used in mathematics.  We say "Laurent series" instead.  So in order to ask your question here, you should include your definition of "Z-transform".  For example, is it $$X(z) ={\mathcal {Z} } \{x[n] \} =\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty} x[n] z^{-n}$$ Is $u(n)$ just any sequence, or is it a particular one?

Comment: Yes, Thank you for the precisions. I edited it. u(n) is the impulse function where u(n)=1 for n>=0 and 0 otherwise.